# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QMainWindowWindowWidget'

Tags: python, pyqt4

so I'm creating a windows application with Python and PyQt4. I use Python 2.7.6. File ui converting I using pyuic4 form_window.ui -o form_window.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindowWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(623, 359)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 40, 371, 281))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 191, 23))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 191, 23))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 191, 23))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_3"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 20, 59, 15))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 59, 15))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 59, 21))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 111, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.zapisz_btm = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.zapisz_btm.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 270, 80, 23))
        self.zapisz_btm.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("zapisz_btm"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 623, 20))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        self.menuForm = QtGui.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuForm.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuForm"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuForm.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Opis", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Adres", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Tytul", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Slowa kluczowe", None))
        self.zapisz_btm.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Zapisz", None))
        self.menuForm.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Form", None))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run my code I have error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/develop/PycharmProjects/untitled/form_window.py", line 18, in <module>
    class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindowWidget):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QMainWindowWidget'
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a class `QMainWindowWidget` in the api: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtgui.html

Are you sure you don't mean to inherit from `QMainWindow` instead?